# Unit tests fail or build fail with MomentJS: undefined is not a function moment default

Tags: angular, unit-testing, momentjs

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'moment_1.default()') in src/test.ts (line 74996)
```

Can somebody please, please, please for Pete's sake, finally port MomentJS to Angular2 and TypeScript and fix this bug that thousands are having?

Or provide a viable, working solution, that works both - with Unit Tests and Production code.

Comment: This is more of a rant than a question.

Comment: Also, [there is already an angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) integration.

Answer (score 0):

For usage inside your templates you can use [ngx-moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment)

To use inside services and components make sure you are using version `2.13.0` or greater and have imported the module with `import * as moment from 'moment';` as described in the official [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/).

That should prevent Moment from being returned as `undefined` in your unit tests